# Converting contour points to bounding box in python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, bounding-box

I am working on medical images with xml files that contain the contour coordinates of the regions of interest. I was able to extract these points but I am unable to convert it into a bounding box which I can use to create a mask for the medical images.

The following are the 'point_px' for one region of interest. 'point_mm' is a similar list of tuples with all zeroes.

```
[
(2462.929932, 995.062988), (2452.830078, 986.978027), (2442.719971, 982.935974), (2430.914551, 983.919678), 
(2420.48999, 988.999023), (2409.370117, 997.083984), (2402.300049, 1008.200012), (2397.25, 1019.320007),
(2393.172363, 1030.600708), (2392.179199, 1041.526123), (2392.179199, 1052.451416), (2394.165527, 1065.363159), 
(2399.131592, 1079.268066), (2410.056885, 1089.200195), (2421.975586, 1094.16626), (2432.900879, 1097.145996), 
(2443.659912, 1095.849976), (2453.399902, 1094.329956), (2465.969971, 1090.060059), (2477.080078, 1081.969971), 
(2485.169922, 1071.869995), (2491.22998, 1060.75), (2491.22998, 1049.630005), (2490.219971, 1038.52002), 
(2484.159912, 1025.380005), (2478.090088, 1015.27002), (2472.030029, 1004.159973)
]
```

The images do not have contours on them so I cannot use the findcontour method.

Comment: Check here please: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d0c/tutorial_bounding_rects_circles.html

Answer (score 1):

You can get a bounding box by finding the lowest x,y values and the highest x,y values (top-left and bottom-right corners respectively).

```py
import numpy as np

# given points
points = [
(2462.929932, 995.062988), (2452.830078, 986.978027), (2442.719971, 982.935974), (2430.914551, 983.919678), 
(2420.48999, 988.999023), (2409.370117, 997.083984), (2402.300049, 1008.200012), (2397.25, 1019.320007),
(2393.172363, 1030.600708), (2392.179199, 1041.526123), (2392.179199, 1052.451416), (2394.165527, 1065.363159), 
(2399.131592, 1079.268066), (2410.056885, 1089.200195), (2421.975586, 1094.16626), (2432.900879, 1097.145996), 
(2443.659912, 1095.849976), (2453.399902, 1094.329956), (2465.969971, 1090.060059), (2477.080078, 1081.969971), 
(2485.169922, 1071.869995), (2491.22998, 1060.75), (2491.22998, 1049.630005), (2490.219971, 1038.52002), 
(2484.159912, 1025.380005), (2478.090088, 1015.27002), (2472.030029, 1004.159973)]

# to numpy array
numped = np.array(points);

# get corners (top-left, bottom-right)
tl = [min(numped[:,0]), min(numped[:,1])];
br = [max(numped[:,0]), max(numped[:,1])];

# print
print(tl);
print(br);
```

The numpy slice numped[:,0] gets all of the x values as a single 1D numpy array

and the other slice numped[:,1] gets all of the y values.

Comment: While this solution does get 2 points, it does not mark the region correctly. It is creating a box that is too large.

Comment: can you plot each of the points as well when doing this? Each edge of the bounding box should touch at least one point.

Comment: Are you expecting the box as top-left and bottom-right points, as top-left point and then the width and height, or as center point and then width and height?